# How to automatically add TFS commit comments to release.txt?

Tags: git, visual-studio, tfs

In a Visual Studio solution, we are using Git as the repo in TFS.

I would like to ensure that all developers' comments get added to a release.txt file so we know what has been done on each build.

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: I suppose you could probably make this work with a post-receive hook. Assuming the release.txt file is itself checked into git, it's going to be really awkward to use, as the server would be adding commits on its own independent of the developers - it just becomes a mess. If I understand your question correctly, then it seems to me that the underlying problem needs a different answer [than a release.txt file]. What's the reason you can't use `git-log` to review what work was done?

Comment: I assume you also use the TFS Build, and in the build results the list of all commits are included - under "Associated changes", with the comments made by the developers.  Isn't that good enough ?